# Best algorithm for finding permutations with constraint of average total value.

Tags: probability, permutations, means

Let's assume I have a random number generator from 0-100 included (only integers) and I generate 5 numbers with it.

I want to know the probability of hitting 80, 80, 80, 80, 80 **with the constraint** that the average number be 80.
In other words, the total "score" has to be 400 and given that, I want the probability of getting 80, 5 times in a row. (I guess assume that the generator's 5 draws will always total 400)

**What I tried**:

I understand that without the contraint, the probability would just be $\frac{1}{101^5}$, and I also understand that considering the constraint, I want to find all of the ways to make 400 total, and the probability will be 1 over that.

What I'm having trouble with is finding a good way to sum up all of the ways to make 400 without just counting them one by one.

I initially felt it would be trivial, but...it's looking pretty hard right now and I'm really not sure how to strategize.

Please don't just give me a result or formula without any explanations. It's for my own understanding, not homework or anything. Ideally I would like to get better at approaching how to solve these kinds of problems, so any insight into how to do that is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not see any permutations so far. Is any random number generated with the same probability?

Comment: @mvw, yes all the numbers are generated with the same probability. Maybe "permutations" is wrong? I guess I meant in the sense that scores of 75, 85, 90, 70, 80 aren't the same as 70, 80, 90, 75, 85 or any other permutation of the same 5 number combination when it comes to calculating the probability, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @mvw, the problem I'm having is coming up with a good way to find all of the ways to make 400 with 5 randomly generated numbers, after which the probability of 80, 80, 80, 80, 80 specifically will just be 1/(all the ways to make 400 in 5 "draws")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look up "stars and bars" - the number of whole number k-tuples which sum to n is given by $$N_{n,k} = \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}= \binom{n+k-1}{n}$$

**Explanation:**  if you want the number of 3-tuples summing to 5 you count the strings consisting of 5 stars and 2 bars where the bars separate the different numbers.

for example `**|***|` represents the 3-tuple $(2,3,0)$

so you need the number of strings of 7 characters ( in general $n+k-1$ ) containing five stars and two bars, all you need to do is to choose what places to put the 2 bars and then fill the rest of the string with stars.

So the number of 3-tuples summing to 5 is $\binom  72$ and the number of 5-tuples summing to 400 is $\binom{400}{4}$

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting!

Comment: This answer can't be right.  There are 3 parameters rather than 2.  For the OP's problem $n=400$ and $k=5$ and the eligible numbers go from 0 to 100 (and call this third parameter $m$).  You've shown the special case where $m=n$ and the OP needs $m=100$.

Comment: A brute force use of "do loops" gets me 4,598,126 arrangements that use 5 numbers between 0 and 100 to sum to 400.  (I'm not smart enough to figure out the general formula.)